# Show that these 5 lines are concurrent using vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

Pentagon $ABCDE$ is inscribed in a circle. For any edge of $ABCDE$, we can draw the line perpendicular to that edge that contains the centroid of the remaining three vertices. Show that these 5 lines are concurrent.

I'm supposed to use vectors for this problem since I just finished a unit on vectors.
I have no idea where to start. Can I get some starter tips?

Comment: but, for symmetry, it is clear that each of the lines will pass through the center, or not ?

Comment: Is the pentagon regular? Then this is obvious by symmetry.